# My games keep black screening?

Tags: windows-7, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

Ive had this problem for about a week or so, i started with nvidia crashing but now games just black screen and windoes gets all pixelated all the time.
any suggestions?

I7-4770k
gtx 770 twin frozr
750w power supply
sapertooth z87
16gb ram

Comment: Provide information on the crash.  What hardware do you have exactly?  What version of the Nvidia driver do you have installed?

Comment: I have a gtx 770 card on a z87 motherboard.
my cpu is a i7 4770k (untouched)
i have 16g ram.
its nothing more special about the crash it just blackscreens bf4 and on minecraft it makes all random colors and crashes after a few mins.

Comment: Update your question with all requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any special error message in after the crash. If no error meager is there you can upload your game log files here.

At least clarify what kind of error you are getting, either software or hardware.

You told you have i7-4770k which has inbuilt Intel HD 4600 graphics, try to unplug your card, run the game in inbuilt graphics, and check. Also check whether the power supply unit is sufficient for the maximum load of your VGA card.

Comment: how do i find the log file ?

Comment: Actually i didn't play the game bf4 yet. Just search the directory with text file (*.txt) and check.

I had the same black screen issue while playing Splinter Cell Blacklist. But fortunately there was two launcher, dx9 and dx11. dx9 worked for me while the dx11 fails. You can try this with your luck.

Another thing, do you have the problem for the particular game or for all games?